# While using MPV player on Ubuntu 22.04 black screen appears

Tags: gnome, video, wayland, mpv-media-player

I am using mpv player on Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland. Every minute of playing, the system goes to sleep. There are no traces in log files.
With 18/20.04 mpv works well.

I found this in the [ArchWiki for mpv](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mpv#GNOME_Blank_screen_(Wayland)):

> mpv may not suspend GNOME's Power Saving Settings if using Wayland
> resulting in screen saver turning off the monitor during video
> playback. A workaround is to add `gnome-session-inhibit` to the
> beginning of the `Exec=` line in `mpv.desktop`.

I tried that, but it didn't help.
How to fix it?

Comment: Can you try installing and enabling the [Espresso](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4135/espresso/) extension and see if it solves your issue?

Comment: Can you share the actual line of your `mpv.desktop` file? Adding `gnome-session-inhibit` did work for me. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499742/how-do-i-prevent-ubuntu-from-sleeping-while-mpv-is-running/1500407#1500407