# How do I prevent Ubuntu from sleeping while MPV is running?

Tags: video, screen, lock-screen

When I watch movies in the Videos app, the screen does not dim or lock while the movie is playing. However, in [MPV](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mpv), the screen dims and eventually locks following my default sleep settings.

In general, I want my computer to fade to sleep/lock when I'm not using it.

Apparently I asked this in 2016 about Video: [How can I temporarily disable my screen lock settings during video playback?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778882/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-my-screen-lock-settings-during-video-playback) but MPV is a different app entirely.

Comment: @user68186 Current LTS. Installed with `apt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per a [discussion in github issues](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/8097) and MPV's [troubleshooting guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mpv#GNOME_Blank_screen_(Wayland)) this is a known issue. What worked for me was to find my `mpv.desktop` file and tweak it to add `gnome-session-inhibit` before MPV launches.

My `mpv.desktop` was at `/usr/share/applications/mpv.desktop` -- FWIW, I had to install `locate` and run `sudo updatedb` to update `locate`'s database before I could use `locate mpv.desktop` to find the file itself to edit it. Line 32 reads:

`Exec=mpv --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui -- %U`

I changed it to:

`Exec=gnome-session-inhibit mpv --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui -- %U`

And after that I was able to play movies with MPV without my computer going to sleep.